# test-geoip.exe test fails on the last 2 tests

Tags: testing, geoip

I have built the geoip-c-api using msys2 and mingw-w64 and after i am runing test-geoip.exe 
It gives me those 2 lines in the error log how i can fix it? Why it's happening?
And my OS is Windows 7 64Bit also the api build is 64bit
also note when i was building it was done with no error

```
======================================
   GeoIP 1.6.3: test/test-suite.log
======================================

# TOTAL: 1
# PASS:  0
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0

.. contents:: :depth: 2

FAIL: test-geoip
================

Test addr 99 yahoo.com failed, got (null), expected US
Test addr 198 yahoo.com failed, got (null), expected US
```

Comment: Does geoiplookup produce the expected results? If so, I would suspect it is just a bad test. Those tests are fragile and should be replaced.

Comment: i don't why it wont get the ip for yahoo.com even when i am connected